# Esiste qualche modo più o meno standard di esprimere in italiano "equipo directivo" di un'istituzione scolastica?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Nel mio paese, la gestione e la direzione di una scuola o di un liceo (non esattamente licei perché il sistema scolastico è diverso, diciamo che sono istituzioni più o meno simili a licei) è fatta da un'équipe composta dal dirigente scolastico e di altri insegnanti che svolgono altre funzioni. I nomi delle diverse cariche e le loro funzioni è stabilito nella legislazione (nella legislazione di ogni comunità autonoma, infatti). Questa équipe è chiamata "equipo directivo" in castigliano e "equip directiu" in catalano ("equipo" e "equip" sono maschili).

Per fare un esempio, una di queste cariche è quella del "jefe de estudios" (cast.) o "cap d'estudis" (cat.), che in inglese si potrebbe tradurre come "head of studies". Spiegare tutte le sue funzioni in dettaglio è un po' complicato ma, per esempio, è responsabile della pianificazione e del monitoraggio di tutte le attività accademiche che svolgono insegnanti e studenti. È anche l'incaricato di sostituire il dirigente scolastico in sua assenza.

Altri membri di questa équipe vengono chiamati con la traduzione letterale dei termini "coordinatore pedagogico" e "segretario pedagogico" (ce ne possono essere altri dipendendo delle dimensioni e della complessità dell'istituzione scolastica).

Ricercando su Internet, ho visto che si parla di "collaboratori del dirigente scolastico" (per esempio, su questo [sito web](https://www.universoscuola.it/collaboratori-dirigente-scolastico-nomina-mansioni.htm)).

Comunque, mi chiedo se esista qualche modo (o modi) più o meno stabilito di denominare al gruppo di persone formato dal dirigente scolastico e da questi collaboratori. Ricercando con Google ho trovato "staff dirigenziale" e "staff del dirigente scolastico", ma non so fino a che punto si tratti di terminologia standard.

Comment: Potresti fare un esempio di cosa sono queste "altre funzioni"? La prima cosa che mi viene in mente è il "consiglio d'istituto" ma sembra una cosa diversa da quello che descrivi. [Qui](https://archivio.pubblica.istruzione.it/scuola_e_famiglia/organi.shtml) trovi una lista di tutti gli organi collegiali della scuola italiana, e non riesco a trovare niente che corrisponda esattamente alla cosa che chiedi.

Comment: @DenisNardin: dare tutti i dettagli sarebbe lungo e complicato, ma ho cercato di aggiungere qualche esempio.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Il "consiglio d'istituto" sembra essere qualcosa di simile a quello che qui si chiama "consell escolar" (in catalano).

Comment: Potrebbe essere “consiglio di presidenza”, che raggruppa preside e vicepresidi. Ma ora il preside si chiama dirigente scolastico…

Comment: @egreg: Ho visto anche "staff di direzione" su parecchi siti web (per fare un esempio, [qui](http://www.liceodarwin.net/it/menu-principale/dirigente-scolastico-e-componenti-lo-staff-di-direzione)).